# Custom Bootstrap carousel with thumbnails isn't working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, thumbnails

I was able to merge http://codepen.io/srkimir/pen/mGbrf and http://codepen.io/transportedman/pen/NPWRGq to create an fading (instead of sliding) carousel with thumbnails as seen in http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/gpZoXz.

However, when I tried to apply this to my code, I couldn't get my code to work. The slides were able to fade in at set interval but I couldn't get the thumbnails and the interval:false to work. Additionally, my dreamweaver text editor told me that there might be a error with the javascript for the thumbnails, saying something about missing "use strict" statement for `var conf = {`. However, I don't understand why it's working fine in codepen but not on actual website. (I'm working on a website on localhost.)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>KINCARDINE DIVE LOCKER</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/productdetails.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#carouselHacked').carousel({
  interval: false
});

;(function(window, $, undefined) {

    var conf = {
        center: true,
        backgroundControl: false
    };

    var cache = {
        $carouselContainer: $('.thumbnails-carousel').parent(),
        $thumbnailsLi: $('.thumbnails-carousel li'),
        $controls: $('.thumbnails-carousel').parent().find('.carousel-control')
    };

    function init() {
        cache.$carouselContainer.find('ol.carousel-indicators').addClass('indicators-fix');
        cache.$thumbnailsLi.first().addClass('active-thumbnail');

        if(!conf.backgroundControl) {
            cache.$carouselContainer.find('.carousel-control').addClass('controls-background-reset');
        }
        else {
            cache.$controls.height(cache.$carouselContainer.find('.carousel-inner').height());
        }

        if(conf.center) {
            cache.$thumbnailsLi.wrapAll("<div class='center clearfix'></div>");
        }
    }

    function refreshOpacities(domEl) {
        cache.$thumbnailsLi.removeClass('active-thumbnail');
        cache.$thumbnailsLi.eq($(domEl).index()).addClass('active-thumbnail');
    }   

    function bindUiActions() {
        cache.$carouselContainer.on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
            refreshOpacities(e.relatedTarget);
        });

        cache.$thumbnailsLi.click(function(){
            cache.$carouselContainer.carousel($(this).index());
        });
    }

    $.fn.thumbnailsCarousel = function(options) {
        conf = $.extend(conf, options);

        init();
        bindUiActions();

        return this;
    };

})(window, jQuery);

$('.thumbnails-carousel').thumbnailsCarousel();
</script>

</head>

<body>
<header>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="productdetails">
        <div class="productbox">
            <div class="productcolumn">
                 <div id="carouselHacked" class="carousel slide carousel-fade productslider" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images/scuba-gear_small.jpg" alt="tank" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="images/alg-scuba-jpg.jpg" alt="scuba" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   <!-- Thumbnails --> 
                  <ul class="thumbnails-carousel clearfix">
                    <li><img src="images/scuba-gear_small.jpg" alt="tank"></li>
                    <li><img src="images/alg-scuba-jpg.jpg" alt="scuba"></li>
                  </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="productcolumn2">
                <h1>Scuba Tank</h1>
                <h2>$30.00</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae lectus a nibh eleifend euismod. Mauris in eros et est malesuada congue. Cras vel porttitor ligula, eu tempus ex. Nunc sit amet leo eu orci fringilla vestibulum ut in eros. Maecenas vestibulum diam lectus, ac pellentesque eros faucibus eget. Mauris a arcu eget justo ullamcorper scelerisque vitae id mi. Fusce egestas luctus leo vel rhoncus. Sed id magna fringilla, feugiat sem id, elementum risus. Donec a consectetur justo, a suscipit enim. Sed ultricies semper est in rutrum. Sed fringilla cursus risus.</p>
                <hr class="grayline">
                <div class="shopsection">
                <div class="qualityselect">
                    <form>
                        <select>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                          <option value="11">11</option>
                          <option value="12">12</option>
                          <option value="13">13</option>
                          <option value="14">14</option>
                          <option value="15">15</option>
                          <option value="16">16</option>
                          <option value="17">17</option>
                          <option value="18">18</option>
                          <option value="19">19</option>
                          <option value="20">20</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="shopbutton">
                    <a href="#" >ADD TO CART</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="grayline">
        </div>
        <div class="productcontent">
        <hr class="grayline">
        <div class="productdescription">
            <h2>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vitae lectus a nibh eleifend euismod. Mauris in eros et est malesuada congue. Cras vel porttitor ligula, eu tempus ex. Nunc sit amet leo eu orci fringilla vestibulum ut in eros. Maecenas vestibulum diam lectus, ac pellentesque eros faucibus eget. Mauris a arcu eget justo ullamcorper scelerisque vitae id mi. Fusce egestas luctus leo vel rhoncus. Sed id magna fringilla, feugiat sem id, elementum risus. Donec a consectetur justo, a suscipit enim. Sed ultricies semper est in rutrum. Sed fringilla cursus risus.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.productdetails { width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.productbox { width: 100%; display: block; margin: 100px auto;}
.productcolumn {width:49%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-right: 30px;}
.productcolumn2 {width:49%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }

/* Bootstrap Carousel slider */
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

/*
WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
now override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
*/
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

/* just for demo purpose */
    .productslider .carousel,
    .productslider .carousel-inner,
    .productslider .carousel-inner .item {
      height: /*100%*/ 200px;
      width: 100%;
    }
ul.thumbnails-carousel {
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}
ul.thumbnails-carousel .center {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.thumbnails-carousel li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.active-thumbnail {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.thumbnails-carousel li { width: 80px; height: 50px;}
.thumbnails-carousel img { display: block; width: 80px; max-width: 100%; height: 50px; max-height: 100%; object-fit: cover;}

.productcolumn2 h1 { padding-bottom: 25px;}
.productcolumn2 h2 { padding-bottom: 10px;}
hr.grayline {  border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.shopsection { width: 100%; display: block; padding: 10px 0;}
.qualityselect { width: 40px; display: inline-block;}
.shopbutton { width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 15px;}
.shopbutton a { background-color: #2a286a; color: #fff; width: 80%; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 5px;}
.shopbutton a:hover { text-decoration: none; background-color: #eb3237; color: #fff;}

.productdescription h2 { padding-bottom: 10px;}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for this and include your `style.css` and  `productdetails.css`

Comment: I commented out my style.css and the thumbnails didn't work. and the css that you saw on this question is from productdetails.css. In fact I tried to comment out anything that might affect those code and the thumbnails didn't work. If you want, I can email you the code I'm working on and you can see it in localhost. Additionally, the code that did work was in this codepen: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/gpZoXz that I was working on to see how it works before applying it to my code.

Comment: Seems to be working fine on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbsrryhy/). Can you check on your console tab if there are errors showing? Probably some resources wasn't loaded.

Comment: All it said that "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ productsdetail.html:24" which is in the javascript code. I did say that there might be something wrong with the code. Can I email you the folder with my code?

Comment: Check my post, if it won't work and we can't see any errors you can email me the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why you getting that "Uncaught ReferencError" is because the Jquery wasn't loaded or finish loading by the time your code was executed.

This was the code where it is throwing the error:

```
$('#carouselHacked').carousel({
  interval: false
});
```

To fix that we put that inside a `$(function() { });` so it will execute when the `DOM` is ready.

Your code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#carouselHacked').carousel({
      interval: false
    });

    // let's put this code also so it won't throw an error when it runs
    $('.thumbnails-carousel').thumbnailsCarousel();
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I've been working all night working on the right image slider with carousel. I went with a different image slider but it didn't work out so I went with bootstrap carousel and I found two different bootstrap codes and I merge it together. Thanks for helping me with that last problem...

Comment: Hey! My client want to add a zoom effect to the image and I was able to in http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/LVMqmJ. but it's not working in my localhost code too...:( the zoom plugin is from http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ and I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532869/using-jquery-zoom-with-bootstrap-carousel

Comment: Never mind. I got it to work. I still don't understand why I need to put the <script> code after the code....